# How to match letters and check that value is present inside array or not using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need one help. I need to check that string is present inside array or not and also it should search letter wise using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$resultArr=array("9937229853","9937229856","9937229875");
$searchValue="+919937229853";
```

Here I need to check that some of the value from `$searchValue` is present inside in array or not. I am doing like below but its not giving me the proper result.

```
$searchValue="+919937229853";
$resultArr=array("9937229853","9937229856","9937229875");
if(!in_array($searchValue, $resultArr))
{
 $flag=1;
}else{
  $flag=0;
}
echo $flag;
```

As per my requirement here result should print `1` because some value from `$searchValue` also present in that array but the echo result is coming `0`.Please help me.

Comment: It is not present. `'+919937229853' !== '9937229853'`

Comment: Thats why I am saying i need to match charcter also.

Comment: Even so. `+919937229853` is not contained in `9937229853`. Is it enough if a part of `$searchValue` is in the array?

Comment: @subhra, does `$resultArr` always contain only numbers?

Comment: yes.Its always contains only numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$searchValue="+919937229853";
$resultArr=array("9937229853","9937229856","9937229875");

foreach($resultArr as $value)
{
    if(strpos($value,$searchValue) || strpos($searchValue,$value) || $searchValue==$value)
    {
        $flag = 1;
        break;
    }
    else
        $flag=0;
}
echo $flag;

I think this will do what you are looking for. in_array() method search string in array but for the exact string. strpos can search substring in long string and return the offset number or the index of substring in the long string.
```

Comment: its working for this particular case but if `$searchValue="9937229853"` it could not work as per expected.

Comment: you can add a condition if(strpos($value,$searchValue) || strpos($searchValue,$value) || $searchValue==$value)

Answer (score 0):

you can try code like below.

```
if(!in_array(substr($searchValue,-10), $resultArr))
```

Comment: Are you sure that `-10` is always the correct value?

Comment: It may be `10 or more also'.

Answer (score 0):

The function below will return `true` if either

- your `$searchValue` is in the array (`in_array`), or
- if any item of the array is a substring of `$searchValue`
  in other words: If part of `$searchValue` is in the array.

This is the code and how you call it:

```
function search($needle, $haystack) {
    // is $needle contained in the array as it is?
    if (in_array($needle, $haystack))
        return true;

    // Is any part of $needle part of the array?
    foreach ($haystack as $value) {
        if (strpos($needle, $value) !== FALSE)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

$resultArr = array("9937229853", "9937229856", "9937229875");
$searchValue = "+919937229853";

$result = search($searchValue, $resultArr);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: always result is coming `false`.

Comment: I added a `var_dump` at the end and then copied the complete code to [phptester.net](http://phptester.net/). It returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchValue="+919937229853";
$searchValue = str_replace("+91","",$searchValue);
$resultArr=array("9937229853","9937229856","9937229875");
if(in_array($searchValue, $resultArr))
{
 $flag=1;
}else{
  $flag=0;
}
echo $flag;
```

User str_replace function replace first three charater from string

Comment: It may not be always `+91` it may be also `+911` or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
$flag=0;
for($i=0;$i<strcmp($searchValue);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<strcmp($searchValue);$j++){
         $part=substr($searchValue,$i,$j)
         array_filter($resultArr, function($el) use ($part) {
             if ( strpos($el, $part) !== false ){
                  $flag=1;
             }
         });
    }
}
```